# angular2-highcharts series highlight

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have an angular2-highcharts chart. I want to highlight select lines of a data series based on which line is clicked. I am using the following piece of code to do so and I get an error saying

> Cannot read property 'series' of undefined.

I have my series predefined, it has name, data, color and width elements.

```
this.options={
    title : { text : 'Sample' },
    legend:{enabled:false},
    plotOptions:{
        series:{
            events:{
                mouseOver:function(){
                var m=this.series.options.id;
                var abc=series;
                var new_series=[];
                for(var i=0;i<abc.length;i++)
                    {abc[i].color='black';}
                abc[m].color='red';
                for(var i=0;i<chart.series.length;i++)
                    {chart.series[i].remove();
                    new_series.push({name:abc[i].name,data:abc[i].data,color:abc[i].color})
                    } 
                chart.addSeries(new_series,false);
                chart.redraw();

                }
            }
        },
    },

    series:series,
    xAxis:{title:{text:'X'}},
    yAxis:{title:{text:'Y'}},
}

$('#conatainer').highcharts(this.options)
var chart=$('#conatainer').highcharts();
```

I am guessing the error is in the way the chart has been referenced. I was not sure how to reference it in typescript and looked up a few examples in java script to do so.

It would very helpful to know how to correct this.

Comment: And what about chart parameter? I don't see that you have defined it in your options before making your chart. and if you are using chart.series and chart is undefined, it will cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve series highlight on click using angular2-highcharts

```
class AppComponent {
    constructor() { 
        this.options = {
            title : { text : 'simple chart' },
            plotOptions:{
                      series:{
                          events: {
                      click: function(e) {

                        let series=this.chart.series;
                        for(let i=0;i<series.length;i++){

                          if(i==this.index){
                             this.chart.series[i].options.color = "#008800";
                             this.chart.series[i].update(this.chart.series[i].options);
                          }else{

                          this.chart.series[i].options.color = "#7cb5ec";
                          this.chart.series[i].update(this.chart.series[i].options);
                          }

                        }

                      }
                    },
                },
            },
            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129],
                color : "#7cb5ec"
            },{
                data: [19.9, 21.5, 6.4, 29],
                color : "#7cb5ec"
            },{
                data: [10.9, 15.5, 30.4, 45],
                color : "#7cb5ec"
            }]
        };
    }
    options: Object;

}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gr96quESX1rTpjn0hfdC)

Comment: can you explain a ittle, better to write about what option did the work